# Problem using expect variable!

Tags: command-line, bash, openvpn, curl, expect

I am trying to automate my vpn using a shell scipt

What I want is to get a webpage (curl) and parse it for password.
If I write a normal script looks something like:

```
var=$(curl -i http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn | grep "Password: <strong>*")
echo ${var:26:8}
```

This outputs a password.

Now, I want to parse this via `expect`, store it, and then run the `openvpn` command:

```
spawn sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-euro2-tcp443.ovpn
expect "Enter Auth Username:"
send "vpnbook"
expect "Enter Password: "
send $pass
```

I am unable to set this `pass` variable properly.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the environment to store the value, and use expect's `env` array to retrieve it:

```
var=$(curl -i http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn | grep "Password: <strong>*")
export passwd=${var:26:8}
expect -c '
    spawn sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-euro2-tcp443.ovpn
    expect "Enter Auth Username:"
    send "vpnbook"
    expect "Enter Password: "
    send $env(passwd)
    interact
'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this same thing for my vpnbook automatic connection. I've created my version using the other answer plus downloading all the needed files and keeping them up to date. It's now a one button script that connects to vpn book.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm vpnbook*
rm VPNBook*
curl -O http://www.vpnbook.com/free-openvpn-account/VPNBook.com-OpenVPN-US1.zip
unzip VPNBook.com-OpenVPN-US1.zip
var=$(curl -i http://www.vpnbook.com/freevpn | grep "Password: <strong>*")
export passwd=${var:26:8}
expect -c '
    spawn sudo openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp80.ovpn
    expect "Enter Auth Username:"
    send "vpnbook\r"
    expect "Enter Password: "
    send "$env(passwd)\r"
    interact
'
```